# Hive/Impala write to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

On Hue, I can write a query using Hive or Impala:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename LIMIT 10
```

The output appears and I can click "export data" and store it on my hdfs folder `user/username/mytestfolder` as parquet. I want to do the exporting from the hive script, and tried versions of:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/username/mytestfolder'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS PARQUET
SELECT * FROM database.tablename
LIMIT 10;
```

but it always returns an error `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Error creating temporary folder on: hdfs://bdp01cdhc01-ns/user/username`

Comment: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'`  ---this is not applicable for PARQUET: `STORED AS PARQUET`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY` is what you want.

You could create a table in the location that you want, using `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement

```
CREATE TABLE x
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/user/username/mytestfolder'
AS SELECT * FROM database.tablename LIMIT 10;
```

Or `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE x LIKE database.tablename  LOCATION 'path';`, followed by an `INSERT` from the other table

**But**, HDFS shoudn't be used to store such small files (only 10 rows)

---

Also, these are for text files, and have no context for Parquet

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

Alternatively, if you have Spark or Pig available, those would also let you save off Hive tables to alternate HDFS locations

Comment: I get the following error `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 0:0 Error creating temporary folder on: hdfs://bdp01cdhc01-ns/user/username/mytestfolder. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE'`

Comment: What query did you use? And does your query user have permissions to modify or create directories in that location?

Comment: The query, `SELECT * FROM database.tablename LIMIT 10`, itself works if ran in the query editor. Now, the user (me?) has permissions in this directory, I created the `mytestfolder` folder directly using the Hue user interface. I can upload, download, delete  files from that location

Comment: That query can be ran two different ways... Either with a CTAS, or an INSERT, so which was it? And Hive itself has settings for user impersonation, which might need configured specifically in HUE to passthrough your username, otherwise all queries would run under some generic hue user, I think.

Comment: I tried with `CREATE TABLE x
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/user/username/mytestfolder'
AS SELECT * FROM database.tablename LIMIT 10;`. I am now looking for an option in Hue to have Hive impersonate me.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of Impala. https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L1367